# Rigorous probability text for math major

Tags: probability, analysis, reference-request

Most probability texts that do not use measure theory seemed to be geared toward engineers and the like, while more advanced texts already assume a strong background in measure theory and Lebesgue integration.

I'm not too familiar with measure theory, (my analysis background is limited to Rudin's PMA Ch. 1 - 10), so I'd appreciate some recommendations that do not assume an analysis background beyond Rudin's PMA.  I'd be okay with a text that uses measure and Lebesgue theory as long as it sufficiently presents the material on its own.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I like Robert Ash's *Real Analysis and Probability.*

Comment: I like this one too.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the book [Theory of Probability and Random Process](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540254846). This is the textbook used in Princeton. By Leonid Koralov, Yakov G. Sinai.

Comment: Perhaps author names might improve this answer!

Comment: Sorry for forgetting.

Answer (score 1):

Williams' Probability with Martingales.

He assumes little background in measure theory but walks you through the development of the necessary machinery, and more importantly, helps you understand why it's necessary. I strongly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I like a recent book by John Walsh [Knowing the Odds: An Introduction to Probability](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=gsmseries&ikey=GSM-139).

Answer (score 0):

"Foundations of Modern Probability" by Olav Kallenberg is imho very good.

It contains a HUGE amount of material and is self-contained.